Docsy edit link are generate with local absolute path
I have install hugo v0.128.2 and Docsy example as a template (last version) on windows 11.
In doc section the edit link is refered the github repo + the local absolute path instead of related path in the project:
like
https://github.com/google/docsy-example/edit/main/C:%5csources%5csite%5cdocsy-example%5ccontent%5cen%5cdocs%5c_index.md

instead of
https://github.com/google/docsy-example/edit/main/_index.md

I got this issue on a update docsy example, so I try to run the vanilla docsy example but I get the same issue.
Others links seems to be ok, only

View page source
Edit this page
Create child page
are with wrong links

Is it a bug or there is somehow a configuration to solve that ?

You should provide the source code in your post or in a repo for testing. Difficult to answer the question without the code.

Thanks for your message, I use docsy example repo last released (0.10) and last hugo (0.128) and hugo 0.125.4.

I mean a repo of your hugo install, in which you are seeing the error.

I don't have a repo for my hugo install. I have download prebuild binary hugo.exe (extended version 0.128.2) from hugo website and I put it in a folder which is in the path.  I have also install npm using nvm and go. Parallely, I made a build in a gitlab-ci and publish on gitlab pages I don't have the issue.

I saw same behavior you describe after I upgraded recently. It was working fine on Hugo v0.115.3 and Docsy v0.7.1 but I noticed it broke when I tried to update to current latest (Hugo v0.138.0 and Docsy v0.11.0). After further investigation, it seems like this broke with this commit https://github.com/google/docsy/commit/435b2e0678694f3812a285a67dfac43f1c8ddd25 which means it broke in Docsy 0.9.0. The change here adds a forwardslash to hugo.WorkingDir when building the paths for the files which most likely works on Linux but introduced the breaking behavior on Windows. I submitted an issue for it here https://github.com/google/docsy/issues/2126
Quickest solution without a fix for Docsy is to do hugo and hugo serve commands in Linux environment, though Docsy should fix their stuff so that the build works on Windows like it did to before.

Thanks for the issue. I didn't check Hugo & Docsy on windows since my post and now I have to, and I find again the issue.
